# Fuzzy sort intervals, with a secondary sorting criterion

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, intervals

I want to sort a list of items according to two critera. Each item contains an interval, and a number.

```
Items[0] = {Interval=[10..30], Number = 7}
Items[1] = {Interval=[20..40], Number = 5}
Items[2] = {Interval=[30..50], Number = 3}
Items[3] = {Interval=[40..60], Number = 2}
```

I want to "fuzzy sort" this list according to the intervals: an order where no interval-lower-bound of an earlier item is bigger than an interval-upper-bound of a later item.

For example `items[3]` should not be sorted before `items[0]`, because `[40..60]` is strictly greater than `[10..30]`. But `items[1]` could occur either before or after `items[0]`, because their intervals overlap.

So a valid ordering could be achieved by sorting by the lower bounds, or the upper bounds, or the midpoints, or any arbitrary number from within each interval.

From all these possible orderings, I want to select an ordering that sorts by `Number` as the second criterion. For all items that could be swapped, because their intervals overlap, I want to swap them so that Item.Number is ascending.

So the following would be a valid order, sorted by `Interval` ascending, then by `Number` ascending:

```
Items[2] = {Interval=[30..50], Number = 3}
Items[1] = {Interval=[20..40], Number = 5}
Items[0] = {Interval=[10..30], Number = 7}
Items[3] = {Interval=[40..60], Number = 2}
```

There are multiple equally valid solution. This would also be a valid order using the same criteria:

```
Items[0] = {Interval=[10..30], Number = 7}
Items[3] = {Interval=[40..60], Number = 2}
Items[2] = {Interval=[30..50], Number = 3}
Items[1] = {Interval=[20..40], Number = 5}
```

Is there an efficient algorithm to find such an ordering, besides brute force?

Is there a name for this type or sort?

Answer (score 1):

Make a graph where each vertex is an interval.

For each pair of vertices: if they don't overlap, add a directed edge between them from the earlier to the later interval.

*<sup>It may be possible to avoid the O(n²) running time we'd get by looping over all pairs. If we sort the intervals by end time, iterating through the intervals in this order would allow us to quickly find all intervals which overlap with any given interval we encounter (we can just look up the latest end time in this list that's before that interval's start time). Then we'd need to figure out how to avoid creating any unnecessary edges - for [1,2], [3,4] and [5,6] there'd be an unnecessary edge between [1,2] and [5,6], because they're connected through [3,4].</sup>*

The edges represent which intervals need to come before which intervals in our sorted list.

Until there are no vertices left, pick a vertex with no incoming edges. Make this the next element in our sorted list and remove all outgoing edges for this vertex.

For the above, if we put all vertices with no incoming edges into a collection sorted by `Number`, we can pick the minimum at each point to enforce the secondary sorting criteria.

This would be O(n²), but could perhaps be optimized to O(n log n).

---

Take your example:

```
Items[0] = {Interval=[10..30], Number = 7}
Items[1] = {Interval=[20..40], Number = 5}
Items[2] = {Interval=[30..50], Number = 3}
Items[3] = {Interval=[40..60], Number = 2}
```

The only edge in the graph would be [10, 30] → [40, 60].

This means we can pick any vertex except [40, 60].

We'd pick [30, 50] first since it has the lowest number between the remaining elements (3 < 5 and 3 < 7).

Then we'd pick [20, 40] since 5 < 7.

Then we'd pick [10, 30] and remove the edge to [40, 60], which would allow us to pick [40, 60].

Finally we'd pick [40, 60].